# When does a finite group $G$ only have a single maximal subgroup containing given $A<G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $A<G$.

When is it true that $G$ has only a single maximal subgroup containing (or equal to) $A$?

The necessary condition is that there must be $x \in G$ such that $\left<A \cup \{x\}\right>=G$ and the order of $\left<x\right>$ is a power of a  prime. In many cases, this is also sufficient -- for instance, if $G$ is abelian. But this is not generally true. The simplest counterexample is provided by $G=S_2 \times C_3$, $A=\left<(e,v)\right>$ where $e$ is the identity and $v$ is any $2-$cycle permutation.

Unless I'm missing something, it is sufficient for there to be $x \in G$ such that $\left<A \cup \{x\}\right>=G$, the order of $\left<x\right>$ is a power of a prime, and either $\left<x\right>$ or $A$ are normal subgroups of $G$. But this condition is not necessary if $G$ is simple nonabelian and $A$ is any of its maximal subgroups, for instance.

EDIT: a slightly weakened version of the sufficient condition presented above is that there is $x \in G$ such that $\left<A \cup \{x\}\right>=G$, the order of $\left<x\right>$ is a power of a prime, and $A$ commutes with $\left<x\right>$ under the product of groups. However, this is still not necessary. In particular, there are examples where the supergroups of $A$ do not form a chain, for instance if $A≅C_2$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G=C_2^2 ⋊C_4$.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is that there is a unique minimal block system preserved by $G$ in the action of $G$ by multiplication on the (left) cosets of $A$ in $G$, but I don't suppose that is what you are looking for!

Comment: @DerekHolt, yeah, that doesn't really do much for me, good point though! Another reformulation would be that there must be $B: A \le B < G$ such that every supergroup of A is comparable (ie. subgroup, supergroup, or equal) with B, and the supergroups of B form a chain.